# Using jQuery-AJAX to page ASP.NET datagrid

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, jquery

Does anyone have, or could point me to, an example of using jQuery to page through an ASP.NET datagrid control?

I would like to page through a large set of data displayed by an ASP.NET DataGrid control however I would like to avoid a page refresh and hence want to use AJAX to get the new sets of data. I would also like to avoid the ASP.NET AJAX toolkit and would like to do it all using jQuery-AJAX. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DataGrid is a server side control that relies on postbacks. jQuery and AJAX are client side technologies. Write a AMSX or WCF service to serve up your data and consume it with jQuery. You can use jQuery templates to make things easier. Or wrap the DataGrid in an UpdatePanel and you will have the poor man's AJAX(sometimes called AJAH).

There may be a jQuery plugin to help with this.

Here's a nice article to get you started:

[Easily build powerful client-side AJAX paging, using jQuery](http://encosia.com/2008/08/20/easily-build-powerful-client-side-ajax-paging-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using jGrid, it´s free, but there are commercial dotnet implementations available.
It´s quite powerfull,you can do almost everything with it. And loading your data is easy to. But, you have to forget the Idea of aspnet datagrid, unless you will use updatepanel(which is very stable and usefull and has nothing to do wiht asp net ajax toolkit)